# Oracle ADF: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when pressing Printable page behaviour 12c

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hello am developing a web application using Oracle ADF and jdev12c. I have a page like below.

[image]

The above page is created using a template. That contains three parts. First part is image, second part is deck with more than one panel group layout (Here deck child value is decided using a value from managed bean of scope session.)and third part is actual content facet in this I have dropped a task-flow(bouded) as a region contain .jsff pages.

My problem is every thing is working fine. af:showPrintableBehavior is not working. When I click on the Printable view button am getting the following exception. After the following exception nothing is working in my application. (If I click on any commndLink it is opening in another tab and repeatedly trying to generate the page content for example the table but not displaying the content)

```
exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.model.RowKeySetTreeImpl.setCollectionModel(RowKeySetTreeImpl.java:315)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXListView$RowKeyFacesBeanWrapper.getProperty(UIXListView.java:300)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.FacesBeanWrapper.getProperty(FacesBeanWrapper.java:61)
    oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.data.RichListView$ListViewBeanWrapper.getProperty(RichListView.java:178)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.getProperty(UIXComponentBase.java:1912)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXListView.getSelectedRowKeys(UIXListView.java:451)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXListView.postCreateCollectionModel(UIXListView.java:157)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCollection.getCollectionModel(UIXCollection.java:1671)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCollection.getCollectionModel(UIXCollection.java:1255)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCollection.getRowKey(UIXCollection.java:493)
    oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.data.RichListView.visitChildren(RichListView.java:103)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.visitChildren(UIXComponent.java:774)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.visitTree(UIXComponent.java:631)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.visitTree(UIXComponent.java:405)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.visitAllChildren(UIXComponent.java:504)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.visitChildren(UIXComponent.java:482)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.visitChildren(UIXComponent.java:774)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.visitTree(UIXComponent.java:631)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.visitTree(UIXComponent.java:405)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.visitAllChildren(UIXComponent.java:504)
```

This is not working in only this page. I have tested this in one empty page that is created without using this template. In that empty page I have created this table and tried with af:showPrintableBehavior and here this behaviour is working fine.

Please help me. How to remove the above exception. Export to excel is working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a clientListener inside the button that prints the page, then stop the event from propagating further:

```
<af:resource type="javascript">
/**
 * Shows a popup from an "action" type event.
 * @param {AdfActionEvent} actionEvent the event being handled
 */
function stopEventFromPropagating(actionEvent)
{
  actionEvent.cancel();

}
</af:resource>


<af:commandButton text="Click Me">
  <af:clientListener type="action" method="stopEventFromPropagating"/>
</af:commandButton>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Marcus. I don't have any button in my page. The following is the code that I have in my page

Comment: <af:commandMenuItem text="Printable View" id="cmi1"
                                                        binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_table.cmi1}">
                                        <af:showPrintablePageBehavior/>
                                    </af:commandMenuItem>

Comment: Ok, you can still try placing an clientListener and cancel event propagation, as described in the blog, see if this helps.

Comment: Ok. When am trying to place clientListener it is asking for method and Type. It is not showing any * symbol after mehtod input box and type contains action, blur and click and many. As he explained in the above blog I can define a method in backing bean. How to map that method for clientListener and what should be the value for type. Thank you.

Comment: You won't need a backing bean method, but javascript function. See the example here, is easy:
http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_clientListener.html. Check the answer again, I updated it with code example

Comment: Hello Marcus. As you said I have added the following code but same problem

Comment: <af:commandMenuItem text="Printable View" id="cmi1"
                                                        binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_table.cmi1}">
                                        <af:clientListener type="action" method="showPopupFromAction"/>
                                        <af:showPrintablePageBehavior/>
                                    </af:commandMenuItem>

Comment: <af:form id="f1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_business_Fin_AP.f1}" usesUpload="true">
            <af:resource type="javascript">
              function showPopupFromAction(actionEvent) {
                  actionEvent.cancel();
              }
            </af:resource> </form>

Comment: Hello Marcus. As you can see in the image. The page have two options. 1.Printable View and 2. Export to excel. If I click Printable view first am getting the above error. But If I press Export to excel first then if I click Printable View the above error is not coming and am getting printable page successfully. Please help me.

Comment: This may be an Oracle I presume... These things are hard to debug, I would suggest you to use "Divide and Conquer" strategy: comment out parts of the page and test again the use case. You may be able to spot a certain component producing this incompatibility.